# HomeController disappeared after running php artisan make:auth

Tags: laravel

I was working on a PHP application and at some point needed to include a login. I did that by running `php artisan make:auth` to generate the authentication files. Later on I realized that my `HomeController` was not the same again. It only contained one function as opposed to my own `HomeController` which had multiple functions.

Is it possible to retrieve my `HomeController`?

Comment: I think it overwrote it.

Comment: If you have source control, yes.

Comment: when you says source control, do you mean some kind of version control like git?

Comment: yup! as in the docs its advised to run the auth command on init the app and not during a project, for his type of issue. And like mentioned in the comments if your uisng git etc then you should be able to.

Comment: Some editors (phpstorm) will save everything in memory. I've discared files in git before and were able to restore them with ctrl+z assuming you've had the file open the entire time.

Comment: If you're using notepad++ you could check for .bak -files location (backup files) if enabled.